# Opencart Authorize.net issues

Tags: php, email, paypal, opencart, authorize.net

I have issues in payment processing.

I am using Opencart 1.5.6.1 And I am using authorize.net and paypal for transactions. Currently Enabled Methods are Paypal Express(works Perfect), Authorize.net(works with issues), Disabled method Paypal pro/Paypal Payflow pro edition.(Disabled as it gets payments but cannot redirect to success page)

Issues I have been facing are:

1. Authorize.net Payments: 
   For every 3-4 orders 1 order is going in as missing order(under sales>orders, Select status as missing order and filter).

I had the problem where every order was going to missing orders and i  added hash md5 value which was optional. But after adding hash 3-4 orders go through without any issues but 4th or 5th order gets missing order tag and it goes there. main worry is I dont get any payments. Contacted Authorize.net but they say there is NO such record of any transaction with the customers name or anyother info. Payment Never reached Authorize.net at all. Any transaction after this would be successful Completely Okay. but again after 3rd or 4th transaction, This repeats itself. I have No payment extension installed. I use core files provided by opencart.

2. Also I had Paypal pro/Paypal Payflow pro edition as a payment method but when customer places order, it never gets redirected to success page. Customer clicks twice and thrice and we get multiple payments. It has very long "Please wait" then Nothing. I tried both Paypal pro and paypal payflow pro but same thing. There is nothing wrong with paypal as i was with them for hours and they say they receive payments just fine.

Another (Maybe) Relevant information is that I have issues with Mail. I get notifications only on emails I provided as Additional Emails. (Under "Additional Alert E-Mails:"). For this also I tried using mail parameters etc but none worked.

Main Email I use is Office365 email. It never gets emails from opencart. when I use gmail in additional alerts, I get emails. I have office365 domain email and gmail on additional alerts section.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you may want to look at, there are several placed where opencart order confirmations can bomb out.

There is indeed an issue with the md5 hash and authorize.net. It's supposedly optional, but I've verified failure if the value is null.  I think as long as there is some matching value on both ends you should be good.

Check that there are ONLY email addresses and commas in the 'additional alert email' field.  I've had orders fail to complete because of an errant carriage return here.

Also, how are you configured to send mail? If you're using smtp, and opencart attempts to send an email that doesn't validate with the smtp service, the order confirmation process will fail.

Opencart has very loose email format validation that may be less strict than third party transactional email providers.  Opencart accepts spaces, commas, and other characters in emails that are technically within email specs, but often aren't considered valid- In our case, an email address with a space in it passed opencart validation, but failed to send through Mandrill returning an error response- Opencart has no error handling for this scenario.